# How to detect if a web site uses New Relic

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I ordered a gig on Fiverr to write a Privacy Policy. The only information I gave is my web site url (https://reseaumusicart.com). The person figured out that I was using New Relic to monitor my webserver. I asked her how she got that information. She only answered that she have her tools...

Does New Relic leave traces in the front end? Do I have an obvious security flaw that exposes New Relic? I'm a bit concern by this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your 404 page has obvious New Relic JavaScript code.

https://reseaumusicart.com/blah

Comment: ...in addition to the [js tracking bits](http://hastebin.com/ewomicagag.xml) included in every single page. :)

Comment: @EEAA No idea how I missed that on first glance, haha. Indeed it does.

Comment: Nice! I didn't notice it had a front-end agent